# A group G contains a cyclic subgroup of the order of the least common multiple of r and s.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$\bf{setting}$

- G is abelian
- H and K are cyclic subgroups of G having the order r and s, respectively.

I want to show that G contains a cyclic subgroup of order lcm(r,s).
So, I have tried as follows :

*Claim. If a and b are generators of H and K, respectively, $<ab>$ is a cyclic group of order lcm(r,s).*

Let n be the order of ab. Then, clearly $(ab)^{lcm(r,s)}$=e, and so n divides lcm(r,s). 
Conversely, **I want to show that $a^n=b^{-n}=e$.** If so, r and s divide n and so lcm(r,s) divides n. Thus, we can complete the proof.

But, I have failed to show it. So, I need some help for this problem.

Comment: This will not quite work. As an extreme example, let $b$ be the inverse of $a$. Then $ab$ has order $1$. But you will succeed if you assume that the orders of $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime. And then you can use this to settle the problem in general.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Then, is my conjecture false in general? If r and s are relatively primes, I can settle this problem, but it is hard to solve general cases.

Comment: The conjecture is correct, it is just the proposed proof which is not. As a hint, some $a^hb^k$ will generate a cyclic subgroup of order the lcm.

Comment: By conjecture is correct I mean there is a cyclic subgroup of the desired order.

Comment: Ah, my conjecture is "I want to show that ~~ " at the above statement. Is it false? i.e. Is it not always true?

Comment: Yes, that is false, my first comment said so. Let $a$ have order $\gt 1$ and let $b$ be the inverse of $a$. Then your $n$ is $1$, but $a^n\ne e$. One can also produce less trivial counterexamples.

Comment: I understand your comment. Thanks a lot!:)